# Broken code after updating Discord.js V14 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'member')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I keep getting this popping up as an error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'member')". Along with this error "ReferenceError: config is not defined"

I am not sure how to fix it, but this is my code. I think I have some variable/code that don't exist. This started happening after I updated from discord.js v13 (I think) to discord.js v14

```js
module.exports = {
    name: Events.PresenceUpdate,
    async execute(newPresence) {
        try {
            const newMember = newPresence.member;
            if(!newPresence || !newMember || newMember.user.bot) return;
            if (!newMember.guild || (newMember.guild.id !== process.env.GuildID)) return;
            if (newMember.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === process.env.VanityRole)){
                if(GuildMember.activities.some(activity => activity.type === "CUSTOM" && activity.state && activity.state.includes(process.env.VanityPhrase))) return;
                if(!GuildMember.activities.some(activity => activity.type === "CUSTOM" && activity.state && activity.state.includes(process.env.VanityPhrase))){
                    const role = newMember.guild.roles.cache.get(process.env.VanityRole);
                    await newMember.roles.remove(role);
                    client.channels.cache.get(process.env.VanityChannel)
                    await reply({
                        content:   `<@${newMember.id}>`,
                        embeds: [removedEmbed],
                        allowedMentions: { parse: [] },
                    })
                }
            }
            if (!newMember.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === process.env.VanityRole) && GuildMember.activities.some(activity => activity.type === "CUSTOM" && activity.state && activity.state.includes(process.env.VanityPhrase) )) {
                await newMember.roles.add(process.env.VanityRole);
                client.channels.cache.get(process.env.VanityChannel)
                await reply({
                    content:   `<@${newMember.id}>`,
                    embeds: [addedEmbed],
                })
            }
        }catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried looking at the Discord.js guide to see if there was something I needed to update, but no luck. I've also tried reverse searching my error on Google and Stack Overflow, but no luck.

Comment: `presenceUpdate` takes 2 params, `oldPresence` (Might be partial!) and `newPresence`. Please update your code to have those two params. You will also need the `User` partial enabled, if you don't know how to do that you can see [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials) guide.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the 2 parameters to include both, and I'm no longer receiving a bunch of errors popping up. However, I have a different error. I think it regards me enabling some partials.

"TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client."

I have `Partials.GuildMember`, `Partials.Message`, `Partials.Channel`, and `Partials.Channel` enabled.

Comment: I tried replacing the Partials with [intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents), but a bunch of errors popped up again.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `GuildPresences` and the `GuildMembers` intent enabled? You will also need to enable them both on the [DDev portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) (Application -> Bot -> Privileged Gateway Intents). Also make sure you have the `User` partial. If it still doesn't work you might try adding the `GuildMember` partial.